# Swift - Change color and size of text when UIButton is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Basically, I have a three buttons on my main screen.

When I select one of these buttons, I would like the text on the selected button to change to bold and change color (blue).

When I select a different button, I would like the newly selected button to change to bold and change color(blue), and the previously selected button to go back to normal. (non-bold and black text)

I have these buttons sending an action to the script.

This is what I have, I can't seem to get it to work. Help would be much appreciated!

```
@IBAction func buttonOne(sender: UIButton){
    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
}
```

I have tried .Highlighted and .Selected on the UIControlState, neither seem to work. I have also tried the following, but I cant get it to work.

```
@IBAction func buttonOne(sender: UIButton){
    sender.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}
```

I figured that since the sender was a UIButton, and it was the button that was clicked, taking the values off of it and resetting them would work. I do believe I am missing something.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want `UIControlState.Normal`

`Selected` does nothing in most cases, and `Highlighted` is only while you're pressing the button. 
See more info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_State

Comment: Thanks! It changed the color to black. Ive been banging my head against my monitor for the last hour and havent been able to figure this out. Thank you! Follow up question though - how do I get the other buttons to change back to black when I hit a new button?

Comment: (Black? Thought you wanted blue?) Connect each button as an IBOutlet property in the view controller, and when one's IBAction is triggered, inside that method also change the other buttons however you want. Probably need a property that remembers which button is the active one (e.g. a number from 1-3 etc). You could also consider using a segmented control instead of 3 separate buttons.

Comment: I would like the active box to be blue, and the inactive boxes to be black. Your suggestions have been very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do with a transform...

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    sender.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8)
}

@IBAction func buttonReleased(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    sender.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Since I have three buttons, I would like to avoid making two functions for each button. If I cant figure out the states, ill try this. Seems like a good solution.

Comment: just hold an array for the 3 buttons and iterate through them in your click function to reset them. then set the clicked-state for the one that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Provide tags to all buttons, connect each button actions to same function and try the following code:

@IBAction func butnClicked (sender : UIButton) {

```
    for tg in 1...2 {
        print(sender.tag)
        let tmpButton = self.view.viewWithTag(tg) as? UIButton
        if tmpButton?.tag == sender.tag {
          tmpButton?.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
        } else {
           tmpButton?.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

Hope will be helping.